"If she did, she might be alive now" -- is this correct?
In Dan Bern's Marilyn, there's a verse that's been bugging me: "Marilyn Monroe didn't marry Henry Miller / but if she did, she might be alive now". The present-tense might be sounds ungrammatical, but I get what it's trying to say and don't know how to fix it.
"Marilyn Monroe didn't marry Henry Miller / but if she did, she might have been alive now" doesn't sound right either, because the have been clashes with the now. It does make sense in the later verse "but if she did, she'd have had more fun", but that's the eventuality where she dies young anyway, so the whole sentence is safely in the past.
More generally said, which tenses do you use to express a hypothetical conditional where the cause is in the past and the effect continues into the present?

The first sounds fine to me. "might have been alive" suggests that she was alive at some previous point, but is not alive anymore.

Similar types of problematic construction have been called the "baseball conditional" or "sports subjunctive" since they are common in sports commentary. For example, "If he passes to Jordan, the Bulls win." Or "If he passed to Jordan, the Bulls win." Or even "He passes to Jordan, the Bulls win." (Note: none of these are subjunctives, so "sports subjunctive" is a misnomer.)

As is very often pointed out here, song lyrics (taken as a corpus) do not constitute a very good representation of English grammar in any register other than their own. For one thing, lyricists often warp their usage to accommodate the melody’s rhythm and so forth. As just one example, consider the original English translation of “The Girl From Ipanema,” in which Astrud Gilberto sang, “But each day, when she walked to the sea // She looked straight ahead not at he.” In that case, it was a non-native speaker who wanted to get the rhyme.

This is indeed wrong; the correct version would be:

Marilyn Monroe didn't marry Henry Miller, but if she had, she might be alive now.

Here's why. There are two reasons one might use the past tense in the protasis of the conditional. The first is the usual one, to indicate past time, as in:

If he paid five hundred dollars for this, he wasted a lot of money.

But the past tense can also be used in the protasis of a conditional to indicate not past time but modal remoteness, i.e. to indicate that a possible situation is hypothetical rather than real:

If he paid five hundred dollars for this, he would be wasting a whole lot of money.

Note the occurrence of the word would in the apodosis--you need a word like would or could or (in your case) might for this construction to work.
But what if a situation is both hypothetical and in the past, as in your example? In the example you provide, we have modal remoteness (since the marriage didn't happen) and also past time (the possible marriage is in the past--it's not a hypothetical event occurring now). When that happens, the protasis has to be made past tense twice, so to speak, resulting in the past perfect:

If she had married Henry Miller, she might be alive now.

In the lyrics you cite, the complement of had is omitted--instead of "had married Henry Miller," we just have "had," with the "married Henry Miller" inferred from context, giving:

Marilyn Monroe didn't marry Henry Miller, but if she had, she might be alive now.

I suspect that the mistake in the original comes from an attempt to make the second half of the sentence use the same tense/aspect as the first, i.e. using "did" to match the preceding "didn't." It could also be because, in the version above, the form of the omitted verb ("married Henry Miller") is different from the one used overtly ("marry Henry Miller").

Thanks for the comprehensive answer. What helped me in particular was the substitution of would/could for might -- then the construction looks correct.

A 'mixed conditional' seems to be required: the 3rd (past) having a present consequence (2nd conditional): If I hadn't gone to medical school, I wouldn't be a doctor (today).
Grammar used in lyrics is often wrong in my listening experiences. It might be so for technical musical reasons such as maintaining a certain number of syllables to the beat etc, or it could be through ignorance of grammar.
